# put on imageview automatically once i click save button

Tags: android, image, canvas, imageview, save

I have a function that saves into a sdcard and I want to put it on the imageview automatically once i click the button save. Please help me, thank you..

here's my code: i want it to put on the tapimageview's ImageView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createpage1);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        mTempDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + "PixiePhotos" + "/";
        //mCurrent = "PXD_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        prepareDirectory();

        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        chooseimage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseImage);
        compositeImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.compositeImageView);
        tapimageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tapimageview);
           // imageView5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            imageView4.setOnTouchListener(this);
            tapimageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" 
                     + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.cork));    


          compositeImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
          chooseimage.setOnClickListener(this);
          imageView4.setImageBitmap(drawingBitmap);

          //tapimageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          //bgimage = tapimageview.getDrawingCache();


         // tapimageview.draw(canvas);
          //canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 90, 0, paint);






          save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Log.v(TAG, "Save Tab Clicked");
                  viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);//i is imageview whch u want to convert in bitmap
                    canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
                    tapimageview.draw(canvas);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(drawingBitmap, matrix, paint);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpstickers, matrix, paint);
                  try {
                    mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBitmap);

                    mCurrent = "PXD_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg";

                    mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable) mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
                    String FtoSave = mTempDir + mCurrent;
                    File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
                    mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                    mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutputStream);
                    mFileOutputStream.flush();
                    mFileOutputStream.close();
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
                  }

                }
              });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To recap:

1. You have an image.
2. You save the image to SDCard.
3. You want to display image in a predefined tapimageview ImageView within the Activity.

I think as long as the file exist in the location you are specifying you should be able to reference it as follows:

```
mFile = new File(FtoSave);
if(mFile.exists()){
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
    tapimageview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
}
```